# How to use a cursor and use scope identity in the same time?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a XML file like this:

```
<FormActions>
    <FormAction>
        <IsPassParams>1</IsPassParams>
        <IsSendEmail>1</IsSendEmail>
        <FormActionID>0</FormActionID>
        <ActionName>Account Full Info. SSRS 24</ActionName>
        <ActionPath>C:/</ActionPath>
        <FormID>536</FormID>
        <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
        <ProgramType>5</ProgramType>
        <CreatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <CreatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <SendVariableID>--here
            <int>9</int>--variableID
            <int>11</int>--variableID
        </SendVariableID>--here
    </FormAction>
    <FormAction>
        <IsPassParams>1</IsPassParams>
        <IsSendEmail>1</IsSendEmail>
        <FormActionID>0</FormActionID>
        <ActionName>Account Full Info. SSRS 26</ActionName>
        <ActionPath>C:/</ActionPath>
        <FormID>516</FormID>
        <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
        <ProgramType>5</ProgramType>
        <CreatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <CreatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <SendVariableID> --here
            <int>8</int> --variableID
            <int>279</int> --variableID
        </SendVariableID> --here
    </FormAction>
</FormActions>
```

and I have a table

```
VariableActionID | VariableID
```

I want to add `VariableActionID` with `FormActionID` created in another table that this data is inserted in.

I used this but it did not work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[frm_Update_frmFormAction]
    @ModuleID INT,
    @FormID INT,
    @XMLID INT,
    @UserID BIGINT
AS
BEGIN TRY
    --1. Delete existing
    DELETE ffa
    FROM frm_Form_Action ffa (NOLOCK)
    WHERE ffa.FormID = @FormID;

    DECLARE @int INT, @formActionID INT;

    --2. Insert new Form Action
    INSERT INTO frm_Form_Action(ActionName, ActionPath, FormID, SeqNo, 
                                ProgramType, IsPassParams, isSendEmail,
                                CreatedDate, CreatedUserID)
        SELECT 
            ActionName = x.ActionName, ActionPath = x.ActionPath,
            FormID = @FormID, SeqNo = x.SeqNo,
            ProgramType = x.ProgramType, IsPassParams = x.IsPassParams,
            IsSendEmail = x.IsSendEmail,
            CreatedDate = dbo.ufn_Get_UTCDate(), CreatedUserID = @UserID
        FROM
            OPENXML(@XMLID, '/Form/FormActions/FormAction', 2)
        WITH
            (ActionName NVARCHAR(255),
             ActionPath NVARCHAR(2000),
             FormID INT,
             ProgramType SMALLINT,
             IsPassParams SMALLINT,
             IsSendEmail SMALLINT,
             SeqNo SMALLINT) x;

    DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR
        SELECT x.[int]
        FROM OPENXML(@XMLID, '/Form/FormActions/FormAction/SendVariableID', 2)
             WITH ([int] INT) x;

    OPEN MY_CURSOR;

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @int;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        @formActionID = scope_identity();

        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.frm_Form_Action 
                   WHERE ProgramType = 5)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.frm_Form_Action_Variables (VariableActionID, VariableID)
                SELECT @formActionID, @int
        END;
    END;

    CLOSE MY_CURSOR;
    DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR;
```

I used the cursor to get `FormActionID` value from `frm_Form_Action` table and insert it inside `VariableActionID` in `frm_Form_Action_Variable` table, but each time I try this, the values inserted correctly in `frm_Form_Action` but it inserts only 1 record in the `frm_Action_Variable` table.

Comment: I believe your NOLOCK hint will be ignored in a DELETE statement, but it can certainly lead to confusion for future developers.  I highly recommend you remove that hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I do not understand your needs, but one thing for sure:

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

This is one approach to get all data in tabular format. Hope this helps:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<FormActions xmlns:xsi="dummy">
    <FormAction>
        <IsPassParams>1</IsPassParams>
        <IsSendEmail>1</IsSendEmail>
        <FormActionID>0</FormActionID>
        <ActionName>Account Full Info. SSRS 24</ActionName>
        <ActionPath>C:/</ActionPath>
        <FormID>536</FormID>
        <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
        <ProgramType>5</ProgramType>
        <CreatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <CreatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <SendVariableID>--here
            <int>9</int>--variableID
            <int>11</int>--variableID
        </SendVariableID>--here
    </FormAction>
    <FormAction>
        <IsPassParams>1</IsPassParams>
        <IsSendEmail>1</IsSendEmail>
        <FormActionID>0</FormActionID>
        <ActionName>Account Full Info. SSRS 26</ActionName>
        <ActionPath>C:/</ActionPath>
        <FormID>516</FormID>
        <SeqNo>1</SeqNo>
        <ProgramType>5</ProgramType>
        <CreatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <CreatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedUserID xsi:nil="true" />
        <UpdatedDate xsi:nil="true" />
        <SendVariableID> --here
            <int>8</int> --variableID
            <int>279</int> --variableID
        </SendVariableID> --here
    </FormAction>
</FormActions>';
```

--the query

```
SELECT fa.value(N'(ActionName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ActionName
      ,fa.value(N'(ActionPath/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ActionPath
      ,fa.value(N'(FormID/text())[1]',N'int') AS FormId
      --ommited some values
      ,fa.value(N'(CreatedUserID/text())[1]',N'int') AS CreatedUserID --returns NULL, no "text()"
      --ommited some values
      ,vInt.value('text()[1]','int') AS vInt
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/FormActions/FormAction') AS A(fa)
OUTER APPLY A.fa.nodes(N'SendVariableID/int') AS B(vInt);
```

The result:

```
+----------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+
| ActionName                 | ActionPath | FormId | CreatedUserID | vInt |
+----------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+
| Account Full Info. SSRS 24 | C:/        | 536    | NULL          | 9    |
+----------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+
| Account Full Info. SSRS 24 | C:/        | 536    | NULL          | 11   |
+----------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+
| Account Full Info. SSRS 26 | C:/        | 516    | NULL          | 8    |
+----------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+
| Account Full Info. SSRS 26 | C:/        | 516    | NULL          | 279  |
+----------------------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+
```

### UPDATE (taken from your - duplicate - follow up question)

Try this query:

```
SELECT fa.value(N'(ActionName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ActionName
      ,fa.value(N'(ActionPath/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ActionPath
      ,fa.value(N'(FormID/text())[1]',N'int') AS FormId
      --ommited some values
      ,fa.value(N'(CreatedUserID/text())[1]',N'int') AS CreatedUserID --returns NULL, no "text()"
      --ommited some values
      ,vInt.value('text()[1]','int') AS vInt
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY fa.value(N'(FormID/text())[1]',N'int'))
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/FormActions/FormAction') AS A(fa)
OUTER APPLY A.fa.nodes(N'SendVariableID/int') AS B(vInt);
```

I added a `DENSE_RANK()`-call to get your `VariableActionId`.

Well, the resultset of this query **is a table** or at least: can easily be used to fill or create a table.

The easiest was to use something like

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(Col1,Col2,...)
SELECT Col1,Col2,... FROM ...
```

This will insert this resultset into your table immediately.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo for helping, it perfectly solved my problem ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try to adapt this code to your needs, change the name of your primary key on the output table

```
inserted.YOUR PK 




declare @inserted as table (sequence int) 

INSERT INTO frm_Form_Action
(
    ActionName,
    ActionPath,
    FormID,
    SeqNo,
    ProgramType,
    IsPassParams,
    isSendEmail,
    CreatedDate,
    CreatedUserID
)
output 
inserted.YOUR PK 
into @inserted
SELECT ActionName = x.ActionName,
       ActionPath = x.ActionPath,
       FormID = @FormID,
       SeqNo = x.SeqNo,
       ProgramType = x.ProgramType,
       IsPassParams = x.IsPassParams,
       IsSendEmail = x.IsSendEmail,
       CreatedDate = dbo.ufn_Get_UTCDate(),
       CreatedUserID = @UserID
FROM
    OPENXML(@XMLID, '/Form/FormActions/FormAction', 2)
    WITH
    (
        ActionName NVARCHAR(255),
        ActionPath NVARCHAR(2000),
        FormID INT,
        ProgramType SMALLINT,
        IsPassParams SMALLINT,
        IsSendEmail SMALLINT,
        SeqNo SMALLINT
    ) x

;with cte_xml as (
select 
row.value('.','int') VariableID
from
  @xml.nodes('/FormActions/FormAction/SendVariableID') t(SendVariableID)
  cross apply SendVariableID.nodes('int') y(row)
 ),
  cte_inserted as (
 SELECT 
    sequence as VariableActionID
 FROM 
    @inserted
)
INSERT INTO dbo.frm_Form_Action_Variables
        (
            VariableActionID,
            VariableID
        )
 select distinct 
  VariableActionID
 , VariableID
 from cte_xml cross join cte_inserted
```